# How to create a list of all members in dsharpplus? (dsharp+)

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

I want to create a list of all usernames/displaynames of all the members in my discord server in dsharpplus.
Here is the code I have now:

```
List<string> users = (List<string>)(await c.Guild.GetAllMembersAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)).Select(member => member.DisplayName);
foreach (string player in users)
{
  Console.WriteLine(player);
  await CreatePlayerChannel(player).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

But it doesn't work for me, also: c.Guild.Members doesn't show the full list of members, because I've been told that members aren't always fully cached.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: i have got same problem

Answer (score 0):

I make it in slash command, but here how to get members list:

```
[SlashCommand("get_members","gets members)]
public async Task GetStat(InteractionContext ctx)
{
    var members = await ctx.Guild.GetAllMembersAsync();
}
```